# Can I use identity strategy and SequengeGenerator at the same time?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

`<hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>`

I will use mysql, oracle11g, postgresql and db2.
And I already use postgreSQL as IDENTITY that has not sequenceGenerator.
Now I try to connect oracle11g, but it doesn't supply identity strategy.
I check it's operate when I using Identity strategy with sequenceGenerator like below code.

```
@Id
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "sfm_user_user_id_seq_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sfm_user_user_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "sfm_user_user_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
  private Long userId;
```

But it's little bit different using IDENTITY without sequenceGenerator and using IDENTITY with sequenceGenerator in postgreSQL.
When I using without sequenceGenerator, it work as Identity and sequence is manged by database(Identity column) but with sequenceGenerator, it is managed by code (I think) not identity column.

i know it work by identity when I using IDENTITY strategy with sequenceGenerator, but actually it is working as sequence strategy.
Why is it happened?